# Arithmetic with pointer types/

Tags: pointer-arithmetic

Some examples of adding and subtracting similarly typed pointers, using numeric and character pointers please.   Using C.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add addresses or the values they point to?

Comment: I can't figure this one out - adding the values of int pointers makes sense, but adding two char pointers together doesn't make sense for values or addresses.  What is the outcome you're expecting?

Comment: And addresses should not be subtracted.

Comment: So, donfox - there is pointer arithmetic which will add a constant value to a pointer, or there is regular arithmetic that operates on the values of dereferenced numerically-typed pointers.  Either of those strike your fancy?

Comment: I am curious what the homework assignment is actually about.

Comment: @Slaks, it's okay to subtract addresses provided you're not subtracting below element 0 of the real array: "char x[10]; char *y = &(x[5]); char z = *(y-2);" is valid.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I meant subtracting one address from another.  (Unless you want to get a length)

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) to know about pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

Here's a practical example which extracts a single character from a C string:

```
char charAt( char *str, size_t idx) {
    if (idx > strlen (str))
        return '\0';
    return *(str+idx);
}
```

Or another, which swaps an integer in an array with the one immediately before it (with no range checking):

```
void swapInts( int *base, size_t idx) {
    tmp = *(base+idx);
    *(base+idx) = *(base+idx-1);
    *(base+idx-1) = tmp;
}
```

In both these cases, `*(pointer+offset)` is identical to `pointer[offfset]` but using pointer arithmetic instead of array offsets:

```
*(str+idx)        ->     str[idx]
*(base+idx)       ->     base[idx]
*(base+idx-1]     ->     base[idx-1]
```

*Warning:* Don't use these verbatim in your homework, have a think about them then write your own. If you copy them verbatim, you will almost certainly be failed since your educators no doubt watch these sites as well.